# Use socket.io in codeigniter

Tags: php, node.js, socket.io

I want to use `socket.io` in codeigniter and I have followed all the process like install express and `socket.io` in root and I also have created the `server.js` file bellow

**server.js**

```
var socket = require('socket.io');
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = socket.listen(server);
var port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
server.listen(port, function() {
  console.log('Server listening at port %d', port);
});
io.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('new_message', function(data) {
    io.sockets.emit('new_message', {
      message: data.message,
      date: data.date,
      msgcount: data.msgcount
    });
  });
});
```

When I run this `server.js` in terminal, it outputs *'Server listening at port 3000'*,
but when I request `localhost:3000` in browser, it shows `Cannot GET /`. I do not understand this error.

Comment: How is this related to PHP/codegniter? Nothing in your question body - only that you want to use it, but issue seems to be on node.js. Or do I miss something?

Comment: whats the issue in node.js,can you tell me?

Comment: its because scoket.io uses ws protocol instead of http. use this app to test your program [Socket.io tester
](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/socketio-tester/cgmimdpepcncnjgclhnhghdooepibakm?hl=en)

Answer (score 0):

You are adressing http request to express router which is not set in your code. Socket.io is sending xhr or socket requests and does not handle http requests. Either use online services like [Socket echo](https://amritb.github.io/socketio-client-tool/) or raise router which will receive your browser request and echo it it via socket to your socket.io instance.